# Do testers need a developer ID to access my Facebook APP?

Tags: facebook

I have added some testers to my Facebook application while it is still in Sandbox mode. I have already added them as testers within a group called testers. However, they are having issues accessing the application directly (while logged in) and the APPs page.

Do these testers need a developer ID to access my application in Sandbox mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved on my end.

Apparently when you add people as testers they don't get a "Developer App" invite like people added as developers do, so the testers need to make sure they are approved for the Developer App at https://developers.facebook.com/apps. Then they should be able to get to your sandboxed app and approve its permissions. The reason for the fact that some people could access it and others not in my case from my group, was that the ones that could access it from the group had already at some point in their past approved the developer app unknown to me. So it seems all users of my group can now access the sandboxed app, but they have to allow the dev app first.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think they do. I have recently added a friend as a tester and they do not have a developer ID/added the developer application.

My app is still in sandbox mode and is an iframe app btw.

Comment: You were able to add them as testers, but were they able to access the sandbox app without becoming developers?